# Как узнать количество знаков до точки и после?

Tags: javascript

Как узнать сколько знаков имеет число до точки и после точки?

Допустим есть такие числа:

```
var num = 14;
var num2 = 14.54;
var num3 = 514.0587;
var num4 = 0;
var num5 = 0.00000008;
```

Нужно вывести так:

Первое число это сколько знаков до точки, второе сколько знаков после точки

```
var num = [2, 0];
var num2 = [2, 2];
var num3 = [3, 4];
var num4 = [1, 0];
var num5 = [1, 8];
```

Comment: `.toString().split('.').map(e=>e.length)`

Comment: @Grundy: с `num5` может быть загвоздка после `toString()`, думаю...

Comment: @UModeL ага, со всеми случаями где только целая часть :)

Comment: `.toString().split('.').map(e=>e.length).concat(0).slice(0,2)` вот так лучше

Comment: @Grundy: я про экспоненту ака Е в числе

Comment: @UModeL, ага, про это тоже не подумал :-) `.toFixed(23).split('.').map((e,i)=>(i?e.replace(/0*$/,''):e).length).concat(0).slice(0,2)`

Comment: @Grundy: теперь вместо количества в дробной части, выдаёт число 23

Comment: @UModeL, для какого примера? :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108363/discussion-between-grundy-and-umodel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const num = 14;
const num2 = 14.54;
const num3 = 514.0587;
const num4 = 0;
const num5 = 0.00000008;

Number.prototype.numberOfCharactersBeforeAndAfter = function() {
 const str = this.toString();
 
 if (str.indexOf('e') === -1) {
  const result = str.split('.').map(i => i.length);
  return {
   before: result[0],
   after: result[1] || 0
  }
 }
 
 const exponent = parseInt(str.split('-')[1], 10);
 const result = this.toFixed(exponent).split('.').map(i => i.length);
 return {
  before: result[0],
  after: result[1] || 0
 }
}

console.log( num, num.numberOfCharactersBeforeAndAfter() );
console.log( num2, num2.numberOfCharactersBeforeAndAfter() );
console.log( num3, num3.numberOfCharactersBeforeAndAfter() );
console.log( num4, num4.numberOfCharactersBeforeAndAfter() );
console.log( num5, num5.numberOfCharactersBeforeAndAfter() );
```

Comment: `e+` тоже допустимая запись

Comment: @Grundy тоже верно, но меня больше смущает другое, почему в JS нет встроенного метода для преобразования экспоненты в строку, я прогуглил не один источник чтобы найти нормальный преобразователь и он мне не нравится, но зато работает, а если работает то трогать не нужно xD

Comment: Потому что это в большинстве случаев не нужно :)